# ruby on rails - how to read json file using ajax?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm using these codes,

```
#In timetable/new.html.erb

<%= select_tag :department, options_for_select(
 @departments.collect{ |d| [d.department_name, d.id]}, nil),{ id: "department_select" } %>



#In timetable controller

def update_lectures
  if params[:department].to_i == 0
    @lectures = Department.find_by(department_name: params[:department]).l    ectures
  else
    @lectures = Department.find(params[:department]).lectures
  end
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :json => @lectures.to_json }
end




#In javascript

$("#department_select").change( function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: window.location.origin + '/timetable/update_lectures',
    dataType: "json",
    data: $("#department_select").serialize(),
    success: function(data){
      var str = '';
      for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      str += '<li>' + data[name] + '</li>';
      }
      $('#lecture-container-body').html(str);
    }
  });
});
```

I want to know in **#In javascript** how can I read the 'data'?

When I use data[name] => "undefined"

When I use data[lecture_name] => **"Uncaught ReferenceError: lecture_name is not defined"** in console

**@lectures will have these columns: id, lecture_name, lecture_division, passfail, .. etc.**

**(there is no 'name' column)**

HELP please

Comment: Avoid using "name" as a variable name in javascript. It's a reserved keyword.

Comment: Have you tried to log `data` to the console and see what it looks like?
the structure of what data is will be what will determine how you use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you´re not extracting the index inside the for loop. So, the array doesn´t have the props you need.

In javascript you can access dynamically props using the brackets notation as you intended, but the property itself must be a String or a reference to a "string like" value...

```
 str += '<li>' + data[i]['name'] + '</li>'; //note the quotes in name!
```

is the same of doing

```
str += '<li>' + data[i].name + '</li>';
```

So, when you´re doing

```
str += '<li>' + data[last_name] + '</li>';
```

the interpreter looks for a variable named `last_name` which throws the error you mentioned.

Comment: It didn't work .. :(.. just printed "undefined"

I want to know what is the problem T.T

Comment: Can you `console.log` the `data` argument? Knowing the structure will be easy to help you. Cheers

Comment: I RESOLVE IT. THANKS ! I used console.log(data)

Answer (score 0):

In your success callback try:

```
success: function(data){
  var str = '';
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  str += '<li>' + JSON.parse(data).lecture_name + '</li>';
  }
  $('#lecture-container-body').html(str);
}
```

The voodoo you need is JSON.parse(). It's the complement of JSON.stringify().

Comment: Katharine, using jQuery and `dataType: 'json'` jQuery do the parse for you, so the `data` argument received is a javascript object.
Using plain javascript you´d be right, but you need to _parse_  the string _before_ it enters the for loop, otherwise you´d be iterating characters...